# Unable to install wine due to libc6 locale issue

Tags: dpkg, wine, dependencies

When I attempt to install wine with the command `sudo apt install wine-devel-amd64` I receive the error
`wine-devel-amd64 : Depends: libc6 (>= 2.38) but 2.35-0ubuntu3.6 is to be installed`. I downloaded libc6 version 2.38 but upon installation I receive :`dpkg: regarding libc6_2.38-1ubuntu6.1_amd64.deb containing libc6:amd64: libc6:amd64 breaks locales (<< 2.38) locales (version 2.35-0ubuntu3.6) is present and installed.` --auto-deconfigure does not work either. What can I do about this? 
 Thank you.

Comment: What repositories do you have configured?

Comment: Translation: You are attempting to install brand new, bleeding edge Wine on a two year old OS. New Wine requires newer dependencies than 22.04 can provide. You have three options: You can use the older version of Wine in the 22.04 repos. Or you can use an older version of upstream Wine. Or you can install a newer release of Ubuntu.

Comment: Trying to bolt new software onto an older LTS release --as you attempted to do-- is one of the top causes of broken systems. The misuse of `sudo` to mangle your package system has consequences.

Comment: Welcome to Askubuntu. What is the reason for attempting to install the newer Wine version? You shouldn't do this unless you actually have a good reason. Usually, someone would simply install a newer version of Ubuntu that is compatible with the version of Wine you need. There are other options but you would need to provide more information on the steps you took to arrive at this problem. For example, If you added a ppa, then you added the wrong ppa version which can easily be fixed but again, we would need more information to help you. Thanks.

Comment: I will retract the close vote if you will please add the additional information needed. To reply back, just begin your reply with @mchid so that I will get a notification. But as it is now, we don't have enough information to answer the question.